# Sliding Menu with Fragment changing

Tags: android, menu, fragment

I use the Sliding Menu library in my app.
The sliding menu is a fragment.

The blue part is the sliding menu when opened.

The red part is static, it doesn't change, it's the main activity btw.
The yellow part is the fragment that change when the user clicks on an item of the sliding menu.

[image: problem with sliding menu and fragments]

Here's what's wrong when I implement it :

In the sliding menu fragment, I listen for the OnItemClick event, and I create a new fragment depending on the position of the item clicked.
After that, I replace the yellow frame id, with the fragment.

```
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment frag = null;
        switch (arg2) {
        case 1:
            frag = new ExpFragment();
            break;

        case 2:
            frag = new FormFragment();
            break;

        case 3:
            frag = new CompFragment();
            break;

        default:
            frag = new ContactFragment();
            break;
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, frag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Looks good huh? Well, no. Here's the logcat exception I got.

```
06-13 09:28:29.739: E/AndroidRuntime(15422): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

So, if anyone has a clue, or can tell me what to look at, that'd be awesome!

TL;DR : Have 2 fragments (bleu and yellow), the blue has to change the yellow. Gives me an exception.

Thanks,

EDIT: The layouts file: 
The activity_main : https://gist.github.com/dommerq/5771887
One fragment item example : https://gist.github.com/dommerq/5771892

Comment: Hmm looks ok... maybe post your layout too?

Comment: And the Fragment code itself?

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below, thanks Stefan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in my fragment java code.

I had :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(com.quentindommerc.flatme.R.layout.f_contact, container);
    return v;
}
```

And I should have :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(com.quentindommerc.flatme.R.layout.f_contact, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

So basically, in the inflate method, put "false" as third parameter.

Edit : Corrected spelling mistake.

Comment: Exactly, wanted to be sure you had that before answering it :) Good that you found out yourself :)

Comment: @Quentin I'm using it in my project. And I'm asking if I created another DrawerLayout in one of my fragments sliding from right and I want to disable it in other fragments. exactly like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wunderkinder.wunderlistandroid .. could you help me in this?